# Prove that $|f(x)|$ is differentiable at $a$ if $f'(a)$ exists and $f(a)\neq 0$

Tags: derivatives, continuity

I'm working on the proof that $|f(x)|$ is differentiable at $a$ if $f(x)$ is differentiable at $a$, provided that $f(a) \neq 0$. There are two cases: (1) $|f(a)| = f(a)$ and (2) $|f(a)| = -f(a)$. Case (1) is obvious - just a matter of substitution. However, I'm a bit uncertain about (2). This is my proof.

Fix $\epsilon /2 > 0$. Assuming that $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+h) - f(a)}{h} = b$. Then there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $|\frac{f(a+h) - f(a)}{h} - b| <\epsilon $ whenever $|h| < \delta$.

Since $|f(x)| = -f(x)$, $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{ f(a+h) - f(a) }{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{ f(a) - f(a+h) }{h}$.

We can write  $|\frac{f(a) - f(a+h)}{h} - b| = |\frac{f(a) - f(a+h)}{h} - \frac{f(a+h) - f(a)}{h} + \frac{f(a+h) - f(a)}{h} - b| \\ \leq |\frac{f(a) - f(a+h)}{h} - \frac{f(a+h) - f(a)}{h}| + |\frac{f(a+h) - f(a)}{h} - b| \\ = 2 |\frac{f(a) - f(a+h)}{h}|+ \epsilon/2  $.

By continuity, there exists $\delta'>0$ such that $|f(a) - f(a+h)| < \frac{\epsilon |h|}{4}$. Take $\delta^* = min\{\delta', \delta \}$. Then when $|h| < \delta^*$, $2 |\frac{f(a) - f(a+h)}{h}|+ \epsilon/2 = \epsilon/2 + \epsilon/2 = \epsilon$.

Then $|\frac{f(a) - f(a+h)}{h} - b| < \epsilon$.

I'm not certain because I first bound $|h|$ by $\delta$ and when I invoke continuity, I put $|h|$ on the right hand side next to $\epsilon$. I'm not sure if that would case an issue. It would be great if you could check for me.

Comment: The proof is essentially wrong, as the assumption $|f(x)|=f(x)$ or $|f(x)|=-f(x)$, while correct for every particular $x$, cannot be invoked for all $x$ with the same sign.

Comment: Why can I not invoke that assumption for all x > 0?

Comment: Because $f$ may oscillate between positive and negative. A more accurate approach would be to assume something about the sign of $f(a)$, and then use continuity to ensure that there is a neighborhood of $a$ such that $f$ has the same sign there. In the latter case you can use the fact that $|x|$ is differentiable away from zero, and so you just have a composition of two differentiable functions.

Comment: Good point! If I start with $|f(a)| = f(a)$ or $|f(a)| = -f(a)$, can I use the same logic as I did in my proof?

Comment: It may be helpful to observe that $|f(x)| = \sqrt{f^2(x)}$.

Comment: It is a theorem that if $f$ is differentiable at $a$ and $g$ is differentiable at $f(a)$, then $g\circ f$ is differentiable at $a$. This is your case, with $g(x) = |x|$. The only hypothesis I see is that $f$ is defined in a neighborhood of $a$ and $g$ is defined in a neighborhood of $f(a)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am confused as to why you are saying so many words about this. Let $g(x) = |x|$. This is differentiable whenever $x \neq 0$. Then $|f(x)| = g(f(x))$. Now use the chain rule. This shows differentiability whenever $f(a) \neq 0$, as desired.

Comment: I still need to prove that $g(x) = |x|$ is differentiable whenever $x \neq 0$, don't I?

Comment: @user1691278 sure, but it's $-x$ on one ray and $x$ on the other, and I'm sure you can show these are differentiable just with the definition!

Answer (score 1):

$f'(a)$ exists $\implies f$ continuos in a

$f(a)\neq0 \implies \exists \delta>0: \quad f(x)>0 \lor f(x)<0\quad \forall x\in I=(a-\delta,a+\delta)$

thus

$\forall x\in I=(a-\delta,a+\delta)$

$|f(x)|= f(x)>0 \lor -f(x)<0 \implies$

$\implies |f(x)|'= f'(x)>0 \lor -f'(x)<0 \implies |f|$ is differentiable in $a$

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps adding a few details, along the lines of gimusi:

Let $f(a) >0$, the case $f(a)<0$ is dealt similarly.

$f'(a)$ exists $\rightarrow$  $f$ continous at $a$.

Let $\epsilon >0$ be given.

There is a $\delta$ such that

$|h| \lt \delta$ implies

$|f(a+h) -f(a)| \lt \epsilon$, I.e.

$- \epsilon +f(a) \lt f(a+h) \lt \epsilon +f(a)$.

Choose $\epsilon \lt f(a).$

Let  $|h| \lt \delta$:

We have for

$x \in (a-h,a+h)$:  $f(x)\gt 0$,

$|f(x)|=f(x)$,

hence differentiable  at $x=a.$

Note:

The theorem:

f differentiable at a, then continous at a,

is a standard proof in textbooks

by considering a linear approximation of the function.